# Markdown/Tex notebook

Tags: note-taking, markdown, latex

I've found typing up mathematical equations on a dummy mathexchange question, is better than writing them out by hand. You get to type the markup/Tex in a cell, and below the output is rendered in real time.

I was wondering if there was anything like a Jupyter Notebook for this.

I believe Jupyter Notebook will only replace the markup/Tex with the rendered output once you click away. Which means you have to read your calculations in Tex (when performing the next operation) which defeats the purpose. The purpose is to have have you intermediate calculations immaculately typeset, to help reduce the cognitive overhead of performing the next operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github now has support for [math in markdown](https://github.blog/2022-05-19-math-support-in-markdown/).

This makes .md gists ideal for doing working, except you have to switch between the plaintext and rendered markdown.

Answer (score 2):

Obsidian allows [MathJax](https://help.obsidian.md/How+to/Format+your+notes#Math) which is a `display engine for LaTeX`. You can switch been edit/view mode pretty easily